# How do languages test their parsing logic?

Tags: parsing, testing, language-design

I can see that the OpenJDK project has a large number of regression tests for functionality in the language libraries, such as [this](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/jdk/file/65464a307408/test/java/lang). However, it is not obvious to me whether the project contains tests for the actual parsing of java code itself. I have found similar lack of coverage in the [CPython repository](https://github.com/python/cpython), where the parser just seems to exist without explicit testing.

Is it common to just assume that the transformation of program text to AST objects is 'given' in a language? Are there examples of languages with explicit test harness for their parsers?